# Xampp error 404 mysql

Tags: mysql, xampp, error404

tengo este problema, a la hora de intentar iniciar Mysql me aparece "Error HTTP 404.0 - Not Found" ya he cambiado los puertos pero no me funciona y lo he desinstalado pero el error sigue igual :´c
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si mas no me equivoco tiene IIS en esa PC y te esta dando un conflicto por que el error es de IIS no de apache // Xampp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la imagen se aprecia que te esta dando conflicto el puerto del apache que por defecto es el 80, sin embargo se ve que puedes levantar apache y mysql.

**Porque?**

Pues como se ve en la linea de apache, debajo de port tiene asignado el puerto 1234, asi que para acceder al phpmyadmin debes hacerlo desde la direccion:

**localhost:1234/phpmyadmin**

Comment: Muchas gracias.